# Framed floats and background colors for captions

Tags: floats, color, captions, framed, floatrow

i wanted to edit my floats. Found the package `floatrow` and got the desired frames easily for them. Now i would like to add a backgroundcolor to the captions. The problem is that the `\parbox`, i inserted to `captionsetup`, is bigger than the frame of the float and doesn't end up with the frame.
I wrote an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow} 
\floatsetup[figure]{framestyle=fbox,
           framearound=all,rowfill=yes}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{box}{
\colorbox{red}{\parbox{\textwidth}{#1#2#3}}
 } 
\captionsetup[figure]{format=box}
%%
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    TEST TEST TEST
\caption{BLA}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

A `\colorbox` adds additional margins, i.e. `\fboxsep`, so one need to subtract it two times from the `\textwidth`.

The easiest way to fix this is to use the pre-defined `colorbox` of the `caption` package which code already respects `\fboxsep`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow} 
\floatsetup[figure]{framestyle=fbox,
           framearound=all,rowfill=yes}
\captionsetup[figure]{box=colorbox,boxcolor=red,slc=off}
%%
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    TEST TEST TEST
\caption{BLA}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that this needs at least v3.3 of the `caption` package (and is not documented yet since I simply did not find the time to document it so far...)
If v3.3 is not available and updating is not an option, one could (of course) adapt the original code by removing extra spaces and subtracting `2\fboxsep` from the `\parbox` width:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow} 
\floatsetup[figure]{framestyle=fbox,
           framearound=all,rowfill=yes}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{box}{%
\colorbox{red}{\parbox{\dimexpr\captionwidth-2\fboxsep}{#1#2#3}}%
 } 
\captionsetup[figure]{format=box}
%%
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    TEST TEST TEST
\caption{BLA}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: mmh ok, thanks for your help. is there any other chance with other packages? Especially i would like to have the `colorbox` ending with the frame, so that there is no white frame around the colorbox.

Comment: @Robert It's not clear to me what you mean by "with other packages" since I didn't changed the packages used. However, I just have added code which works with older versions of the `caption` package, too.

Comment: Your code you added works fine, thanks for that, but it's not exactly the result i wished. I would like to have the `colorbox` been surrounded by the frame. I don't like the small white space between `colorbox` and frame. Any suggestions to solve this problem? Thanks for your help!

Comment: \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup{style=BOXED, frameset={\fboxsep0pt}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{box}{\colorbox{red}{\makebox[\dimexpr\captionwidth]
 {\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-7pt}{\vspace{1ex}#1#2#3 \vspace{1ex}}}}}
\captionsetup{format=box}
%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
 TEST TEST TEST
\caption{BLA}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

Answer (score 0):

Just solved the problem by changing `\frameset`, adding an additional `\makebox` and some `\vspace`'s:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup{style=BOXED, frameset={\fboxsep0pt}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{box}{\colorbox{red}{\makebox[\dimexpr\captionwidth]
    {\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-7pt}{\vspace{1ex}#1#2#3\vspace{1ex}}}}}
\captionsetup{format=box}
%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    TEST TEST TEST
\caption{BLA}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```